# Draw circle with lines in it and check if mouse is inside the circle- Java Graphics- Geometry

Tags: java, geometry, awt, java-2d

Using Java graphics, I tried to draw a circle, draw lines inside it, then check if the mouse is inside the circle and print the position of the mouse.

The lines I draw exceed the circle and when I click inside the borders of these lines, but outside the circle, it assumes the mouse is inside the circle since the limits I gave to x and y actually form a square.
[this is how my circle looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iihF.png)

How can I find limits for x and y such that the lines won't exceed the circle and it will print "inside" only when the mouse is inside the circle?

[this is how it should actually look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmieg.png)

Here is my code

```
public class Circle extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    
    int x,y,i;
    JLabel label =new JLabel();


    public void SetLayout(int x, int y, int w, int l, Component c){
        c.setLocation(x, y);
        c.setSize(w, l);
    }
    
    public Circle()
    {   
            Container con = getContentPane();
            setLayout(null);
            SetLayout(10, 10, 70, 20, label);
            con.add(label); 
            this.setSize(1000,500);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            addMouseListener(this); 
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);   
        
        g.drawOval(300,50,400,400);

        g.setColor(Color.cyan);       
        for (i = 2 ; i < 400 ; i += 5){
              g.drawLine(300+i, 50 , 300+i, 450);
        }
                
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    
                label.setText( ((double)x-500)/100+"  "+((double)y-250)/-100 );
                
        g.drawLine(0, 250, 1000, 250);
        g.drawLine(500, 0, 500, 500);
        g.drawString("(0,0)",501,265);
        g.drawString("1",601,265); 
        g.drawString("-1",401,265); 
        g.drawString("2",701,265); 
        g.drawString("-2",301,265); 
        g.drawString("3",801,265); 
        g.drawString("-3",201,265); 
        g.drawString("1",503,165);
        g.drawString("-1",503,365);
        g.drawString("2",503,65);
        g.drawString("-2",503,465);
             
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();       
        
        if ((y >= 50 && y <= 450 && x >= 300) & x <= 700){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inside");
                }    
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Outside");
                }
                    
                repaint();
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Circle();
    }
        
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { 
        }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)  { 
        }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0){ 
        }
}
```

Maybe there can be a solution like calculating the clicked point's distance from the center and check if the distance is smaller than the radius. But still, this wouldn't solve the exceeding lines problem.

Answer (score 0):

With Trigonometry:
By using the inverse cosine function you can get the angle between the x-axis and the point on the circle for that x coordinate. Then by plugging that angle into the sin function you can get the y position of that point on the circle.

```java
Point circleCenter;
int radius;
int lineDistance;


for (int x = -radius; x < radius; x += lineDistance) {

    float double = Math.acos(x / radius);

    int y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;

    int top = circleCenter.y + y;
    int bottom = circleCenter.y - y;


    g.drawLine(x + circleCenter.x, top, x + circleCenter.y, bottom);

}
```

If you have time, how about recearching about trigonometry
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html
it really is a fascinating subject and essential for any programmer.

Checking if the mouse is inside the circle:

```java
Point mousePosition;
Point circleCenter;
int radius;

Point centerToMouse = new Point(mousePosition.x - circleCenter.x, mousePosition.y - circleCenter.y);

bool mouseInside = (int)Math.sqrt(centerToMouse.x * centerToMouse.x + centerToMouse.y * centerToMouse.y) <= radius;
```